# Imported fbx files look exploded in 2.82 but not 2.8

Tags: import, transforms, .fbx

I was working on this scene in 2.8 but it kept crashing so I got 2.82 but when I opened the file, all the fbx objects looked exploded. Can you please help. 2.8 keeps crashing to the point where it unusable after some time
[image: this is the scene in 2.8]

[image: this is the same file in 2.82]

The above are the exact same scene

So, I just hit render in 2.82 and it render fine. I still don't know why the mesh is displaying wrong

[image: rendered in 2.82]

Comment: Try exporting after applying scale,rot,loc for the objects using Ctrl+A

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not trying to export the file, I'm just trying to continue my work in 2.82 to avoid the frequent crashing in 2.8

Comment: Did you directly opened 2.8 .blend file in 2.82 or exported and opened in 2.82... I'll try creating that error in my pc

Comment: I directly opened the 2.8 .blend file in 2.82